# SQL query to retrieve record having both codes present

Tags: sql

How to return the rows having 2 codes present?

For E.g. : i need to search customer in a table for which i have codes present both "A" and "B" (these codes present in column named customer_code).

```
 Customer ---> 123456
 Customer_code ---> A
 Customer_code ---> B
```

Then my query should return Customer "123456".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WHERE` to filter for A and B. Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure there are two different codes.

```
select customer
from tablename
where customer_code in ('A', 'B')
group by customer
having count(distinct customer_code) = 2
```

Alternatively, use `INTERSECT`:

```
select customer from tablename where customer_code = 'A'
intersect
select customer from tablename where customer_code = 'B'
```

Comment: There can be other customer_code apart from "A" and "B" as well but we need to concentrate only on these 2 codes, whether both of them are present or not..

Answer (score 0):

This is the schema I used to execute the query:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
(
  Customer long,
  Customer_code varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME values(1,'A');
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME values(2,'A');
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME values(1,'B');
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME values(3,'A');
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME values(3,'B');
```

And the quesry I used to get your result is:

```
SELECT a.Customer from TABLE_NAME as a,TABLE_NAME as b
WHERE a.Customer_code='A' and b.Customer_code='B'and a.Customer=b.Customer
```

I got the result:
1
3

as both had 'A' and 'B' as their codes.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.